# Why are there no diccussions of hypercharge conservation or Dirac hypercharge monopoles?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, electroweak, magnetic-monopoles

The Maxwell equations can be derived from an equation for a spin 1 field with $U(1)$ symmetry. From this field equation is possible to postulate Dirac monopoles by simply roting the real and complex parts of the field.  I believe there is another concept of monopoles and I am refering to Diracs original idea.   There is no reason I am aware of to believe in this type of monopole but the pediction is obvious and has not been refuted.   If monopoles exist the charge current would become a complex number.   Whether the number is complex or real, the $U(1)$ symmetry requires that charge be conserved by a simple and difficult to avoid calculation.   Now, whether the electromagnetic force is the only vector field with $U(1)$ gauge invariance observed depends how the word observed is defined.    It could be said the $B$ meson field whose current is hypercharge has been observed because electroweak theory is verified.   At high enough energy, there is an equation for the $B$ meson.  Based on the proofs previously mentioned, the hypercharge monopole could be postulated, and conservation of hypercharge could derived.
There is something wrong with the above statements.   I have found no theory of Dirac type hypercharge magnet like monopoles (no formal jargon for the idea either), and no law of hypercharge conservation.  Black holes are often said to conserve electric charge but not other quantum numbers.   What am I missing?

Comment: In our world, through EW SSBreaking, the U(1) of hypercharge is "broken" ~ cancelled/obscured and you could think of it as morphing to the U(1) of electromagnetism specified by [weak mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle).  The only surviving massless gauge field with infinite range is thus the photon, the only survivor of this process, relevant to Gauss's law applied to black holes.

Comment: Clearly I did not realize  this is a consequence of symmetry breaking but the other half of the question relates to monopoles.   Why cannot a b meson monopole be postulated with respect to the electtoweak epoch or earlier.

Comment: You probably might, if you forfeited EM monopoles.

Comment: If I can paraphrase what you are saying: if in a simplistic way, one defines a vector field with U(1) symmetry, defines the current of the vector field using weyl spinors, then apply the Dirac quantization condition before introducing the effects of electroweak symmetry breaking, then the Dirac quantization condition could not hold for QED.   Obviously starting with properties of gauge, spin and interaction comes from Weyl's approach and may not be compatable with all aspects of the standard model, but I would like to know if I understood your comment.

Comment: You seem to think that QED and hypercharge exist independently, which is not sound. Enhanced with weak isospin, they are equivalent alternatives to each other. Before delving into fancy topology, make sure you appreciate the equivalence….

Comment: I used neither fancy math nor toplogy.   The question is why I cannot view the B meson simply as a vector boson with U(1) gauge and apply the dirac quantization condition.   I thought your answwer was that there would be observable consequences.   If you mean do not start by trying to find a formula to derive Lagrangians from basic principles say so.

Comment: The B meson is only effectively massless in the primordial universe particle plasma soup, where monopole solutions are hardly definable... Can you focus your question?