# Why there are no Dirac $B $ boson monopoles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spinors, complex-numbers, magnetic-monopoles

This differs from an earlier [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/774839/2451) in that the writing is new and hope better, it uses MathJax, and it gives some details about the particle that poses a problem for certain commonly used theories of the photon.   The questions is what exactly is the error associated with the particle, which never seems to be discussed.
The object is to determine if electrodynamics can be defined by the $U(1)$ gauge invariance, the spin 1, and coupling to other fields.  This is done by analogy to the the Weyl equations, which can be derived by applying an infinitesimal boost to particle that transforms by the group $SU(2)$ using generators: Pauli matrices.  If $ H$ is a scalar time derivative and  the following quaternion momentum  operator is defined: $p= \sigma_1 p_1\ + \sigma_2p_2\ + \sigma_3p_3 $
This gives Right spinor: $\langle H\rvert\psi_R+\langle p\rvert\psi_R=0$
Left spinor:   $\langle H\rvert\psi_L+\langle p\rvert\psi_L=0$
$H = i\partial_t $is theHamiltonian operator, $p_i = i\partial_i$ are momentum operators and $\sigma$ 's are Pauli matrices.   Weyl spinors have 2 components. I am using Planck's units. The equivalent for a complex vector field is to use generators of $SO(3)$: $S_i$.   For right polarization, using Einstein notation.
$$\langle H\rvert ( \overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B )+ \langle\S_i\overrightarrow p_i\rvert\(\vec(E)+i\vec(B))  =0$$
For left polarization:
$$\langle H\rvert ( \overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B )- \langle\S_i\overrightarrow p_i\rvert\(\vec(E)+i\vec(B))  =0$$
$\overrightarrow E$ and $\overrightarrow B$ are real three vector fields, and the above equation correspond exactly to 2 of Maxwell's equations for free space.  Vector field with SU(2) and SU(3) gauge invariance are different.  This Dirac like version of  Maxwll's equations was first used by Majorana in 1928 to describe single photon wave functions.   This form of the wave function can be normalized , so it is more suitable for single photons than the usual description.   These equations however, dexcribe 3 vectors and the source of the wave equation is a 4 vector (the current).   To fix this I describe the vector function as the vector part of a quaternion:
$$ \overrightarrow E +i\overrightarrow B = E_1\sigma_1 +i B_1\sigma_1 +E_2\sigma_2 +iB_2\sigma_2+E_3\sigma_3 +i B_3\sigma_3$$
H and p from the Weyl equation can be exactly the same operator:
$\langle H\rvert\(\overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B )+\langle p\rvert (\overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B)=0$ and $\langle H\rvert\(\overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B )-\langle p\rvert (\overrightarrow E +i \overrightarrow B)=0$.   The four parts of the quaternion are linearly independent so, the scalar part of quaternion must equal zero, this gives $ Div ( \overrightarrow E + i \overrightarrow  B ) = 0 $. Gauss' law for empty space. I can use the exact operator in the Weyl equation as the Maxwell equations, because 3+1 dimensions relate to 4 components of a quaternion.   More dimension would not be as neat, but I believe there is a way to express a similar equation in any number of dimensions.   To describe the equation with sources, it is necessary to get beyond single particle approximations, which cannot be summarized here, so I will give you pages of interest from Peskin and Schroeder's Quantum Field Theory.   Coulomb's law is derived on page 125, which means  that to reasonable approximation $Div( \overrightarrow E + i \overrightarrow B ) = \rho $. Here $\rho$ is a real number.   Of course, to make the equation covariant there has to be a current $\overrightarrow j$  (real quaternion). So, the approximate equations now become: $ \langle H \rvert  ( \overrightarrow E)+i \overrightarrow B) +  \langle P  \rvert  (\ overrightarrow E+i \overrightarrow B ) =\overrightarrow j $  and  $ \langle H \rvert  ( \overrightarrow E)+i \overrightarrow B) -  \langle P  \rvert  (\ overrightarrow E+i \overrightarrow B ) =\overrightarrow j $   If j is an interaction term with a charged scalar or spinor field, the  equation holds.   Interaction terms are discussed on page 75 of Peskin and Schroeder.    Weyl's proof that electric charge is conserved using the U(1) symmetry would also work. The analogy to Weyl's equation is very strong because in both cases a wave equation is obtained by squaring a quaternion.   Now the equation has clearly interchangeable E and B values, until current is added.    In fact if the Dirac quantization condition is applied, the argument for the Dirac monopole becomes evident, and j can be replaced by a complex number, if Dirac monopoles exist (I understand they still have proponents).
If I am true to the program of using analogy to the Weyl equation, then this argument would apply to the epoch when the Weyl equation was valid (before Fermion's have mass), and the field I just described is not the photon field but the B meson field.   This seems to imply a Dirac type monopole theory for the B meson field.   Let's suppose the particle is scalar with only the unique charge that would lead to hypercharge monopole behavior.    In terms of the Weinberg angle the field strength in the current universe would be proportional to $cos(\theta_w\)sin(\theta_w\)$ times the field of the real Dirac monopole.  The particle would be invariant under U(1) gauge transform. It would remain a means to guarantee  the quantization of electric charge.  It would seem the same particle could not also emit W0 because the resulting photon field would have not only magnetic field, but fractional electric charge. There are no original theories used to compute this, but a mere application of a known theory to an obvious problem, so it seems a basic a mistake.  The mistake seems to undermine the idea that the photon field derives simply from symmetry under SO(3) rotation and U(1) transformation.   I would like to know why it does not.